# Nested parameter pack expansion fails

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to write a transform function which takes as input

- a functor, the number of those arguments is the same as the number of input `tuple`s.
- a arbitrary number of `tuple`s

and outputs the transformed `tuple`.

We assume the input tuples having the same type.

For example, the following code snippet should perform a *plus* operation of the tuples, resulting a `tuple` of `{5, 7, 9}`.

```cpp
 auto t = transform(
                     [](auto i, auto j) {
                       return i + j;
                     },
                     std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3), 
                     std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6));
```

**Code**:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#include <iostream>

template <size_t idx, typename... Ts>
using get_nth_type = std::tuple_element_t<idx, std::tuple<Ts...>>;

template <typename Func, size_t... indices, typename... Ts>
auto transform(Func f, std::index_sequence<indices...>, Ts&&... input) {
  return std::make_tuple(f(std::get<indices>(std::forward<Ts>(input))...)...);
}

template <typename Func, typename... Ts>
auto transform(Func f, Ts&&... input) {
  return transform(f, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<get_nth_type<0, Ts...>>::value>(),
                   std::forward<Ts>(input)...);
}

int main() {
  auto t = transform(
                     [](auto i, auto j) {
                       std::cout << i + j << '\n';
                       return -i;
                     },
                     std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3), std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6));
  // Desired output: 5
  //                 7
  //                 9
  std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << ", " << std::get<1>(t) << ", " << std::get<2>(t);
  // Desired output: -1
  //                 -2
  //                 -3
}
```

**Error message**:

```
error: pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs
  return std::make_tuple(f(std::get<indices>(std::forward<Ts>(inputs))...)...);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

It seems that the `indices` and `input` are expanded in a wrong order. But I cannot figure out what the correct way is.

[Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dZEwvAI6PHuTeXyk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you want the `Ts`/`input` pack to be expanded by the first pack expansion and the `indices` pack by the second pack expansion, but both `indices` and `Ts`/`input` appear as part of the operand of the first pack expansion and so they are expanded in parallel with the first expansion, not leaving anything to expand for the second one.

You can avoid this by doing the first expansion inside another function call and the second outside of it:

```
template <std::size_t index, typename Func, typename... Ts>
decltype(auto) transform_impl(Func& f, Ts&&... input) {
  return f(std::get<index>(std::forward<Ts>(input))...);
}

template <typename Func, size_t... indices, typename... Ts>
auto transform(Func f, std::index_sequence<indices...>, Ts&&... input) {
  return std::make_tuple(transform_impl<indices>(f, std::forward<Ts>(input)...)...);
}
```

See https://wandbox.org/permlink/c9YquHFlWlFYM0KN.